# Why some stages of axial compressor has the same blades height?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

As in title. The only answer which I have for now, is "to reduce production costs". But are there reasons based in fluid dynamics?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Basically, the task of a compressor is to add energy to the fluid flow. Pertinent forms of energy here are pressure *and* kinetic energy. The geometry of the compressor duct is determined by the balance of these objectives. Notice that geometry of the duct includes both the (axial) cross section of the duct as well as the flow angles at the duct entrance/exit (i.e., how much "swirl" you have at these points). The latter parameter depends on the choice of airfoils for the compressor blades and compressor type (radial versus axial compressor).

Bottom line, there's no simple answer to your question. There's substantial volumes written about the topic of compressor design.

Reduction of production cost, on the other hand, rarely plays much of a role, since production costs only depend weakly on geometry in the first place. Exceptions may be for extremely low-cost devices (turbochargers in cheap car engines, perhaps).